# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I'm trying to get documents in brews collection from Firestore.

What is wrong with my code?

Help me somebody who is used to Flutter and Firebase.

```
////brew list from snapshot
List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((document) {
      return Brew(
        name: document.data()['name'] ?? '',
        strenght: document.data()['strength'] ?? 0,
        sugars: document.data()['sugars'] ?? '0',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

**Attached screenshots regarding error**:
[image]

Comment: For anyone checking this question, please check the duplicate for the correct answer to this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610111/after-updating-cloud-firestore-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-ob

Answer (score 3):

According to the cloud_firestore plugin github:

```
/// A [DocumentSnapshot] contains data read from a document in your [FirebaseFirestore]
/// database.
///
/// The data can be extracted with the data property or by using subscript
/// syntax to access a specific field.
```

So perhaps this modification to your code would work:

```
List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((document) {
      return Brew(
        name: document['name'] ?? '',
        strength: document['strength'] ?? 0,
        sugars: document['sugars'] ?? '0',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

Comment: I tried this method also. After removing ".data" the error disappeared. But when i run the project it shows errors "as An exception was throw by _MapStream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List<Brew>> listened by"

Comment: @PATHimaranga Can you post the rest of the error as well?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for document.data[] instead of document.data()[]

document.data is a getter that returns Map<String, dynamic>, so you'd just query it as document.data['someKey'] instead of document.data()['someKey']

So this code should work:

```
List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((document) {
      return Brew(
        name: document.data['name'] ?? '',
        strength: document.data['strength'] ?? 0,
        sugars: document.data['sugars'] ?? '0',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

Comment: You mean |name: document.data['name'] ?? " "|. But ierror shows data is an object.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: My bad. It seems the API was updated a while ago. My code works for the previous versions, and I haven't migrated yet, so I wasn't aware.

Comment: @PATHimaranga does document['name'] work for you?

Comment: nope, because of API update. After the update data cant be used without parenthesis.

Comment: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/
Check the "Document and Query Snapshots" on this page and let me know if that works for you? @PATHimaranga

Comment: @Zac: [`QuerySnapshot.docs`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html) returns a [`List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>`] and in [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html) and in those [`data`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot/data.html) is defined as a method. So it seems to me that the `()` are required.